My time series dataset has multiple categories for each time point (multiple trend lines), how can I forecast using ARIMAX?
My dataset looks like this:



Date
Store Number
Department




01-01-2013
1
Automotive


01-01-2013
1
Grocery


01-01-2013
2
Automotive


01-01-2013
2
Grocery


01-02-2013
1
Automotive



There are 54 store numbers and 33 departments. Therefore, each day has 1782 records with sales information. And the dates go all the way from 01-01-2013 to 08-15-2017. I need to forecast the sales for each department and each store number for the next 15 days. Typically in time series problems, there is one trend line and one measure or an aggregated measure. In this case, there are a large multitude of trend lines (one for store number 1 and automotive, one for store number 1 and grocery, etc.).
I was planning to try the ARIMAX forecasting model because there are exogenous variables to be included but did not know how to handle the multiple trend lines. Does one hot encoding the categories for each day fix my issue to where it tracks only one trend line for the category in question? Or does ARIMAX not handle this? Is there another model that I should try in this instance?
I'm new to time series data so I wanted to see if there is a way to make ARIMAX work in this instance or if should be looking another direction. I also want to use multiple models to compare which one works better.
